# addEventListener click issue

Tags: javascript, html

Im struggling with a weird problem. Im creating FAQ to my site and I want to create button that hide/reveal answers to questions.
And here is the problem... reveal function works perfectly and unhide my answer but it doesn`t work when I want to hide it again. Ive tried to put if into if but it doesnt work too. Couldnt even find answer in google so far.

Maybe I`m trying to reinvent the wheel. If somebody know how to create this in easier way I would appreciate that.

```js
const getHiddenElement = document.querySelector('.hidden-text1');
const getBtn = document.querySelector('.reveal-button1');

getBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let counter = 0;

  if (counter == 0) {
    getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
    getBtn.value = 'Hide';
    counter = 1;
  } else {
    getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    getBtn.value = 'Reveal';
    counter = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="question-1">
  <p>Who am I?</p>
  <input type="button" value="Reveal" class="reveal-button1" />
  <p class="hidden-text1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque turpis tellus, aliquam vitae faucibus ac, volutpat varius nibh. Maecenas vitae dictum nisi, vel tempor turpis. Integer eget arcu ut arcu pretium ultricies. Nullam eros odio, blandit eu tellus
    vel, tincidunt auctor orci.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `counter` variable is local and is reinitialized at every click. You can put it as a global and it will work as you expect.

```
let counter = 0;
getBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter == 0) {
        getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
        getBtn.value = 'Hide';
        counter = 1;
    } else {
        getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        getBtn.value = 'Reveal';
        counter = 0;
    }
});
```

Another option would be to check the element style instead of using a variable:

```
getBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (getHiddenElement.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
        getBtn.value = 'Hide';
    } else {
        getHiddenElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        getBtn.value = 'Reveal';
    }
});
```

Comment: Holy, I wasn`t even thinking about moving variable out of function. Thank you, first option works exactly how I wanted it to work but in second solution I have to press twice to reveal the content for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the function is called, the counter variable will be assigned with zero, irrespective of its previous value. To solve this issue, Globally declare the `counter` variable.